# Boolean algebra: (A'+B)(A+C)

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have a little problem with this expression:

```
x = (A'+B)(A+C)
```

I know it can be simplified to:

```
A'C+AB
```

since ive used some software to simplify it, but i simply can't see how it is done.

This is what i've done so far:

```
(A'+B)(A+C)         =>
A'A + AB + A'C + BC =>
0 + AB + A'C + BC   =>
AB + A'C + BC
```

I just fail to see how i can do this differently and get to the correct result.

Comment: + is `or`, and side-by-side values indicate `and`, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we are trying to prove:

```
AB + A'C + BC = AB + A'C
```

Using the Identity Law `X = X1`, the left side can become:

```
AB + A'C + BC1
```

Inverse Law `1 = X' + X`

```
AB + A'C + BC(A + A')
```

Distributive Law `X(Y + Z) = XY + XZ`

```
AB + A'C + BCA + BCA'
```

Associative Law `(XY)Z = X(YZ)`

```
AB + A'C + ABC + A'BC
```

Commutative Law `X + Y= Y + X`

```
AB + ABC + A'C + A'BC
```

Distributive again

```
AB(1 + C) + A'C(1 + B)
```

Finally, the Null Law `1 + X = 1`

```
AB(1) + A'C(1)

AB + A'C = AB + A'C
```

Comment: I know the comments are not for a "thank you", but here it is anyway: Thank you for the very clear solution (with comments)!